# Finding largest 2x2 "square" of values in array C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

For my assignment I have to take in an array of values, save them to a second array and print out a "square" of the 4 highest values. This means the "square" for which the sum of its elements is the greatest in the array.

```
Example:  Given the array    1    2    3     4
                             5    6    7     8
                             9    10   11   12     

 the output should be       7      8      
                            11    12
```

I was originally trying to use sets of nested for loops to find and store each of the subsequent largest values into the second array, but can't seem to figure out the proper algorithm. What I have so far just gives me the same value (in this example's case, 12). Also, I have come to realize that this way won't allow me to keep the formatting the same in the second array.

What I mean is that if I'm saving the largest number found into array b[0][0], it will be in the wrong spot, and my square would be off, looking something like:

```
12 11
10 9
```

Here's what I have so far:

```c
int main(){

int og[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}, new[2][2]={}, rows;
int columns, i, high,j,high2,high3,high4;

high = new[i][0];
high2= high - 1;
high3= high2 - 1;
high4= high3 - 1;
rows = 3;
columns = 4;

for (i=0; i<=rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<=columns; j++){
        if (high < og[j][i])
        high = og[j][i];            
    }        
}

for(i=1;i<=rows;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=columns;j++){
        if(high2 < og[j][i])
        high2= og[j][i];
    }
}
printf("max = %d, %d\n", high, high2);
//return high;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: This `int og[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}, new[2][2]={}, rows, columns, i, high,j,high2,high3,high4;` hurts my eyse you know that you can split it right?

Comment: Thank you, @erip , my simple brain cannot think of any other way to figure this out!

Comment: @iharob I will fix it now.

Comment: I did find [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/). Not an exact fit, but see what you can do with it in the meantime.

Comment: @bravesaint I don't see your code calculating the sum of the current square, why? Also **your code has this `for (j = 1 ; j < = columns ...` etc. which is wrong in c, because in c arrays start at the `0`th indedx.**

Comment: @erip I am trying to figure out exactly what is being done there, a bit over my head at the moment but I'll keep at it. Thank you!

Comment: @iharob I was doing that to try and "skip" over a previously found value. I was just honestly trying *something* different to try and get a different result. And I didn't try to calculate the sum because I figured that would be something to do later on... I just have no idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logic should go roughly as follows (I dont have a compiler atm to test it, so let me know in the comments if i made a derpy error):

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int max = 0;
int sum = 0;
int i_saved = 0;
int j_saved = 0;

for(i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++){
   for(j =0; j < columns -1; j++){
       sum = og[i][j] + og[i][j+1] + og[i+1][j] + og[i+1][j+1]; //sum the square
       if (sum > max){
         max = sum;
         i_saved = i;
         j_saved = j;
       }
   }
}
```

Since OP is asking for the values used in order to save to another array, all you have to do is retrieve the values again!  We have the indices saved already, so this should be relatively trivial.

```
int [][] arr = [2][2];
arr[0][0] = og[i_saved][j_saved];
arr[0][1] = og[i_saved][j_saved+1];
arr[1][0] = og[i_saved+1][j_saved];
arr[1][1] = og[i_saved+1][j_saved+1];
```

The same way we summed them, we can also use that logic pattern to extract them!

Comment: Although you do need to save the `i` and `j` values that gave the best sum.

Comment: simple enough, adding

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks - thank you for the reply! How would I go about saving these individual integers into the second array?

Comment: @bravesaint I'll add that for ya

Comment: @bravesaint Hopefully that helps

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks, thank you so much! Would someone mind explaining the logic behind the how this determines the largest numbers? I really would like to grasp as much theory as possible and keep learning.

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks nice solution, you beat me. :)

Comment: @bravesaint Grab a piece of paper and try to follow my code by drawing pictures, it should start to make sense.  It is essentially moving a 2x2 square around the array, visiting each value, finding the sum of the values and saving it if it is bigger than the old one.

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks, thank you! That helps a lot. I ran the code and got the answers "1 2 5 6" though, was it something I implemented wrong?

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks here is a copy of my code using your solution: [http://pastebin.com/j853iTSJ]

Comment: @bravesaint Link broken

Comment: @bravesaint Nevermind, just a typo in the link.  You didnt set rows/columns.  Mine was a rough outline, you still need to make sure all the variables are set

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks d'oh!! Didn't even realize I missed that. Getting an error message saying it cannot open the file, going to try and get this sorted! Thanks again!

Comment: @bravesaint No problem, thats what stack's for!

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks, I guess since I "have you", after initializing both [rows] and [columns],  do you have any idea why I would be getting error message: "1d returned 1 exit status"? I searched it up and found it is a symbol or function not being declared?

Comment: @bravesaint My best guess is it is how you are declaring new.  Id rename it something else and initialize it on its own line.   Consider getting valgrind

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks hahahahaha, oh goodness me... I didn't realize I had left the explorer open... got it fixed! Disregard please.

Answer (score 1):

I created this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int Mat[3][4]={{1,  2,  3,  4},
                  {5,  6,  7,  8},
                  {9, 10, 11, 12}};

    int maximum = 0;
    int Max_2x2[2][2] = {{1, 2},
                         {5, 6}};


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            maximum = max(Mat[i][j]+Mat[i][j+1]+Mat[i+1][j]+Mat[i+1][j+1], maximum);
            if(maximum == Mat[i][j]+Mat[i][j+1]+Mat[i+1][j]+Mat[i+1][j+1]) {
                Max_2x2[0][0] = Mat[i][j];
                Max_2x2[0][1] = Mat[i][j+1];
                Max_2x2[1][0] = Mat[i+1][j];
                Max_2x2[1][1] = Mat[i+1][j+1];
            }

        }
    }
    cout << maximum << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout << Max_2x2[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
38   // maximum solution
7 8  // output array
11 12
```

This is obviously not a **general** solution, but it works for your example.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Seeing it done a different way is really helpful for a beginner like myself!!!!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark EyeOfTheHawk's solution as the answer!

Answer (score -2):

```
int new[2][2]={}
```

I'm not sure this is valid.  You might need to specify a `0` value for each cell.  Even it it's not required, it's good practice.

```
high = new[i][0];
```

I don't see where `i` has been initialized.