# Finding largest 2x2 average in a 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix, average

I'm trying to find the largest 2x2 average in a matrix. I have found a person who shares a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287163/finding-largest-2x2-square-of-values-in-array-c) to mine however, their solution does not work.

Below is my code:

```
//Part B
        //Finding deepest 2x2 area
            int rowX, colX, ac1Row, ac1Col, ac2Row, ac2Col, ac3Row, ac3Col, ac4Row, ac4Col;
            float largestArea = 0;
            for(rowX = 0; rowX < dataRow - 1; rowX++){
                for(colX = 0; colX < dataCol - 1; colX++){

                    float area = (oceanData[rowX][colX] + oceanData[rowX][colX + 1] + oceanData[rowX + 1][colX] + oceanData[rowX + 1][colX + 1]) / 4;
                    if(largestArea < area){
                        largestArea = area;
                        int ac1Row = rowX; int ac1Col = colX;
                        int ac2Row = rowX; int ac2Col = colX + 1;
                        int ac3Row = rowX + 1; int ac3Col = colX;
                        int ac4Row = rowX + 1; int ac4Col = colX + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Display results
            cout << endl << "The deepest 2x2 area is: " << largestArea << " m" << endl;
            cout << endl << "The coordinates are: (" << ac1Row << "," << ac1Col << ")" << " " << "(" << ac2Row << "," << ac2Col << ")";
            cout << "(" << ac3Row << "," << ac3Col << ")" << "(" << ac4Row << "," << ac4Col << ")" << endl;
```

I'm using a .txt file with my data which is 6 by 6 (Data stored in oceanData, size stored in dataRow and dataCol) My output gives me the average (supposedly), however, when I try to output the coordinates I get strange numbers:
ex.

```
The coordinates are: (4356788,0),(0,0),(0,0),(8,0)
```

Anyone see where my problem is?
Thanks!

Comment: You declare new variables `acRow` ... etc  in scope of `if`. You don't need keyword `int` before them.

Comment: Good catch...its always the simple stuff that you miss! That actually fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the variables on each loop:

```
   int ac1Row = rowX; int ac1Col = colX;
```

But you don't even need all 8 variables, you can save only the coordinates of a single corner and calculate the others.

Consider this

```
       int acRow, acCol;
        float largestArea = 0;
        for(int rowX = 0; rowX < dataRow - 1; rowX++){
            for(int colX = 0; colX < dataCol - 1; colX++){

                float area = (oceanData[rowX][colX] + oceanData[rowX][colX + 1] + oceanData[rowX + 1][colX] + oceanData[rowX + 1][colX + 1]) / 4;
                if(largestArea < area){
                    largestArea = area;
                    acRow = rowX; 
                    acCol = colX;                        
                }
            }
        }
 cout << endl << "The deepest 2x2 area is: " << largestArea << " m" << endl;
 cout << endl << "The coordinates are: (" << acRow << "," << acCol << ")" << " " << "(" << acRow  << "," << acCol + 1  << ")";
 cout << "(" << acRow + 1 << "," << acCol << ")" << "(" << acRow + 1 << "," << acCol + 1 << ")" << endl;
```

Comment: That fixed it, I completely oversaw the fact that I defined them twice. Also, appreciate the simplification, thanks!